# PHP Group array by values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => ing_1_ing 
     [1] => ing_1_amount 
     [2] => ing_1_det 
     [3] => ing_1_meas
     [4] => ing_2_ing 
     [5] => ing_2_amount 
     [6] => ing_2_det 
     [7] => ing_2_meas 
)
```

And I want to group the values into an array like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array(
             [0] => ing_1_ing
             [1] => ing_1_amount
             [2] => ing_1_det
             [3] => ing_1_meas
          )
   [1] => Array(
             [0] => ing_2_ing
             [1] => ing_2_amount
             [2] => ing_2_det
             [3] => ing_2_meas
          )
)
```

There may be many other items named like that: `ing_NUMBER_type`

How do I group the first array to the way I want it? I tried this, but for some reason, `strpos()` sometimes fails:

```
$i = 1;     
foreach ($firstArray as $t) {
            if (strpos($t, (string)$i)) {
                $secondArray[--$i][] = $t;
            } else {
                $i++;
            }
        }
```

What is wrong? Can you advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to achieve, if you want to split array by chunks use `array_chunk` method and if you are trying to create multidimensional array based on number you can use `sscanf` method in your loop to parse values:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($firstArray as $value)
{
    $n = sscanf($value, 'ing_%d_%s', $id, $string);

    if ($n > 1)
    {
        $result[$id][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ary1 = array("ing_1_ing","ing_1_amount","ing_1_det","ing_1_meas","ing_2_ing","ing_2_amount","ing_2_det","ing_2_meas");
foreach($ary1 as $val)
{
    $parts = explode("_",$val);
    $ary2[$parts[1]][]=$val;
}
?>
```

This creates:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ing_1_ing
            [1] => ing_1_amount
            [2] => ing_1_det
            [3] => ing_1_meas
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ing_2_ing
            [1] => ing_2_amount
            [2] => ing_2_det
            [3] => ing_2_meas
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($firstArray as $value)
{
  preg_match('/^ing_(\d+)_/', $value, $matches);
  $number = $matches[1];
  if (!array_key_exists($number, $result))
    $result[$number] = array();
  $result[$number][] = $value;
}
```

Basically you iterate through your first array, see what number is there, and put it in the right location in your final array.

**EDIT**. If you know you'll always have the numbers start from `1`, you can replace `$number = $matches[1];` for `$number = $matches[1] - 1;`, this way you'll get exactly the same result you posted as your example.