# How to group an array containing strings?

Tags: php

I have an array which contains strings and I need to group them accordingly. Please advise.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => string1 
  [1] => string1 
  [2] => string2 
  [3] => string2 
  [4] => string3 
  [5] => string1  
      )
```

I need the output as follows:

> `string1`
>   `string2`
>   `string3`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [`array_unique()`](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Group array by values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929455/php-group-array-by-values)

Comment: also see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php

Comment: did try array_unique yet.. will give a try..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

From:`http://in3.php.net/array_unique`

Answer (score 1):

First, use `array_unique()` to get rid of the duplicates, then use `sort()` to put them in order:

```
$new_array = array_unique( $orig_array );
sort( $new_array );
print_r( $new_array);
```

I'm assuming sort because your output is sorted, but that may also be the natural output of removing the duplicates in the example you provided.  If you don't want them sorted, just remove the `sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

[array_unique](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique) — Removes duplicate values from an array

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_unique such as

```
$new= array_unique($old);
```