# How to group rows using tcpdf

Tags: php, yii, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate reports. I displaying the results from a mysql query using foreach loop. I want to group the results using a value in the mysql result set. For example the result set has three fields voucherno,itemname and suppliername. So the same voucher number will have many items. I want to group it using voucherno and display the items of each voucherno using tcpdf.Please help.

Comment: Please include what you already tried, some code?

Comment: I have searched a lot and got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929455/php-group-array-by-values But I don't know how to modify it for my need

Comment: `GROUP BY voucherno` in your SQL statement.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't want to use GROUP BY in sql. I want to group using array values

Comment: Seems like a backwards solution to me, but now you have your answer. Iterate the resulset and build a new array with the index being `voucherno`. Please attempt some code and come back with it if you have difficulties.